# What is the standard name of this control?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

What is the technical name (widely accepted) for these little individual items in the HTML collections below?

[image]

[image]

I cant for the life of me remember the name of these little things(Little things being the little items in the collection with delete icons) Im looking for them online. The best name I have found (which does not result in any widespread name) is "pill"

Im looking for them in bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap `tags` I think is what you are looking for

https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I am getting close. http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/

Comment: There are tons of 3rd party stuff out there, JQuery page has a lot of good ones.